# Can $\sum_{i=a}^{b}p^{i}\binom{i}{a}\binom{b}{i}$ be simplified?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to compute a complicated thing, and I end up with terms like:

$$\sum_{i=a}^{b}p^{i}\binom{i}{a}\binom{b}{i}$$

$a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, $0<p<1$.

I don't see a way to make this simpler. Am I missing something or is this the simplest thing that I'm going to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be simplified. Note that for $0\leq a\leq b$,
$$\binom{i}{a}\binom{b}{i}=\binom{b}{a}\binom{b-a}{i-a}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{i=a}^{b}p^{i}\binom{i}{a}\binom{b}{i}=p^a\binom{b}{a}\sum_{i=a}^{b}\binom{b-a}{i-a}p^{i-a}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Ted Well done!

Comment: (Reposting my comment to correct mistakes.) Shiny! I didn't know this identity. A change of index leads to $p^{a}\binom{b}{a}\sum_{i=0}^{b-a}p^{i}\binom{b-a}{i}$, and we recognize a binomial identity, so it becomes $p^{a}\left(1+p\right)^{b-a}\binom{b}{a}$. Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = a}^{b}p^{i}{i \choose a}{b \choose i} & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{b}{b \choose i}p^{i}\bracks{z^{a}}\pars{1 + z}^{i} =
\bracks{z^{a}}\sum_{i = 0}^{b}{b \choose i}\pars{p + pz}^{i} \\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{a}}\bracks{1 + \pars{p + pz}}^{\, b}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{1 + p}^{b}\bracks{z^{a}}\bracks{1 + {p \over 1 + p}\,z}^{\, b} \\[5mm] &
\pars{1 + p}^{b}{b \choose a}\pars{p \over 1 + p}^{a}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{p^{a} \over \pars{1 + p}^{a - b}}\,{b \choose a}} \\ &
\end{align}